# How to create a configuration file in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, configuration-files

For my assignment, I've been asked to create a configuration file. The specification says "your code should accept and use configuration files in this form. Each line gives information about a House, Meter, Appliance, Person or task". I've never created or used a configuration file before and I can't find too much on the internet about how to create one so that's why I'm asking this question in case anybody has has any advice they could share on how to create one. Apparently the configuration file must look something like:

```
House:
ElectricMeter:25,false
WaterMeter:52
Kettle:25
ElectricCooker:
ElectricShower:
TV:
Refrigerator:
WashingMachine:3,0,2
Person:Dave,35,M
Shower:28
Cook:30
DoWashing:40
Person:Fiona,34,F
TurnOnTV:33
TurnOffTV:36
Cook:45
Shower:48
```

I have the program that should be able to create something like this I'm just not sure how I actually create one in the first place. Information such as where in NetBeans you have to go to create one and what they're used for would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: It's just a file. With text inside. You can use any text editor to create it. I don't have a NetBeans running, but I guess you can just right-click on the folder where you want to create this file, choose "New file", choose the name you want, and type the text in the editor.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for your help.